# Prelims Probability

Tags: probability

A confused college porter tries to hang $n$ keys on their $n$ hooks. He does managed to hang one key per hook, but other than this all arrangements of keys on hooks are equally likely.

Let $A_i$ be the event that key $i$ is on the correct hook, find the probability that at least one key is on the correct hook.

I found this question from the course material from Oxford and I have no idea of completing it. Would anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We count the complement:

$$P(\text{at least one key on correct hook})=1-P(\text{no key on correct hook}),$$

and this is the problem of counting [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). Using the formula in the link, the answer to your question is

$$1-n!\cdot \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.$$

Deriving this formula is straightforward with the Principle of Inclusion Exclusion.

Comment: You need to divide by $n!$ when calculating $P(\text{no key on correct hook})$. The formula you used simply counts the derangements.